# custom button deployment

Tags: button

I have created a custom button on contact role which will redirect to new case page along with pre-populated some value in the case object and assign to the queue. Then I updated page layout Now I have to deploy this button to QA sandbox. Could anybody tell me how to deploy a button procedure please and what components I have to deploy here?

Object: Account/Contact/Contact role

Pagelayout

Comment: How did you create a custom button on Contact Role? It only lets you configure picklist values. Are you sure you are not using any Custom VF solution?

Comment: Are you talking about a button on the Account page layout's Contact Roles related list?

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty I created a button under custom object name contact role from button, links and action

Comment: @BrentBow yes. A button on Account page layout's Contact Roles related list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying a custom button is really straightforward and can be done using change set.

- Enable org connections between source and target org. You can access it under "Deploy -> Deployment Settings"
- Setup a change-set in the source org
- Push change-set to target org

Include following items in the change-set:

1. Custom Button
2. Account/Contact page layouts

and simply deploy to target org (QA Sandbox).

Comment: THanks. Do I have to take profile as well for this deployment ?

Comment: No profile is not required.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to deploy components from one org to another org. As @Salesforcemarty highlighted the procedure using **Change Set**. It is one of the simplest method to move components from one org to another.

Another way is to use a tool called as **ANT**. **ANT** can be used to deploy components from one org to another. You need to configure **ANT** in your machine. Refer to this [guide](https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/) for configuration of **ANT**. It is **open-source** software. Once you've configured ANT, follow below steps:

1. First you need to prepare **package.xml** which contains details about your components which needs to be deployed. In your case it would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account-Appointment Layout</members>
        <members>Contact-Event Layout</members>
        
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types> 

    <types>
        <members>Contact.Custom_button</members>
        <name>WebLink</name>
    </types>

<version>34.0</version>
</Package>
```

2. Prepare **build.properties** which contains credentials of source and destination orgs and **build.xml** contains commands which are configured for **ANT**. A Sample code for **build.properties** and **build.xml** can be found at [github/mrohit/ant](https://github.com/MRohit/ANT-Deployment).
3. Once all of these things are ready, simply use those commands to **retrieve** components, **validate** them and finally **deploy**.

You might think it is lengthy process but here are some [plus points using **ANT** over **Change Set**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/ant-vs-other-deployment-tools/1012).